# Adding HTTP headers from the CXF service implementation

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf, jax-ws

I am currently implementing soap service and I need to call one soap service (Service B) from another soap service (Service A). From service A, how to set the HTTP headers not SOAP headers of out going soap request to service B.

Currently I am using JaxWsDynamicClientFactory as follows,

```
JaxWsDynamicClientFactory dcf = JaxWsDynamicClientFactory.newInstance();
Client client = dcf.createClient(localhost/services/test?wsdl");

results = client.invoke(new QName(namespace,operation), service parameters);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add headers using the CXF RequestContext.  For example, to add a header named `Header-Name` with the value `headerValue`:

```
    JaxWsDynamicClientFactory dcf = JaxWsDynamicClientFactory.newInstance();
    Client client = dcf.createClient(localhost/services/test?wsdl");
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Map<String, List<String>> headers = (Map<String, List<String>>) client.getRequestContext()
            .get(Message.PROTOCOL_HEADERS);

    if (headers == null) {
        headers = new TreeMap<String, List<String>>(
                String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
        client.getRequestContext().put(Message.PROTOCOL_HEADERS, headers);
    }       
    headers.put("Header-Name", Collections.singletonList("headerValue"));
    results = client.invoke(new QName(namespace,operation), service parameters);
```